# JPA CriteriaBuilder with embedded ElementCollections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to query from an object which has an embedded entity that contains an ElementCollection

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum {VALUE1, VALUE2}

data class MyObject(

    @Embedded
    val embedded: EmbeddedObject? = EmbeddedObject(),
)


@Embeddable
data class EmbeddedObject(

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = MyEnum::class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "t_my_enum", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "fk_my_object")])
    @Column(name = "enum_value")
    @Enumerated(value = STRING)
    val enumValues: Set<MyEnum> = mutableSetOf(),
}
```

I'm now trying to filter results to contain a set of values from `MyEnum`. 
Current approach (which is not working):

```kotlin
    val myFilter = mutableSetOf(VALUE1)
    val criteria: CriteriaBuilder = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
    val query: CriteriaQuery<MyObject> = criteria.createQuery(MyObject::class.java)
    val root: Root<MyObject> = query.from(MyObject::class.java)
    root.where(root.get<EmbeddedObject>("embedded").get<Set<MyEnum>>("enumValues").`in`(myFilter)))
```

This fails with the following error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [VALUE1] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]`

I also tried to join the EmbeddedObject or the enumValues columns, both did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `EmbeddedObject` has no corresponding database table, the solution was to `join` it and `MyEnum` instead of using `get`:

```
root.where(root.join<MyObject, EmbeddedObject>("embedded").join<EmbeddedObject, MyEnum>("enumValues").`in`(myFilter))
```